# JavaScript--Make <BR/> tag active and inactive

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

Is there any way to have a JavaScript function make a `<BR/>` tag active and inactive?

Comment: In what sense should it be active?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "active" and "inactive"?

Comment: Does "inactive" mean it doesn't actually break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give it an ID, then use the following code so that the newline is no longer displayed.

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'none';
```

Then use

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display = '';
```

to make it display again.

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/fT9Zp/1/) is a jsFiddle demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I switch between `''` and `'none'`, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you've put an `id` attribute on your `<br/>` tag (so `<br id="some_id"/>`), then make sure that the string in the `getElementById()` call matches that id.

Comment: @JackStone Switch to `"inline"` instead of `""`. Also, instead of giving each `br` an ID, use `getElementsByTagName` or a jQuery selector. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fT9Zp/2/) based on Anthony's jsfiddle

Comment: Use a class rather than id if you have more than one, javascript getElementById stops looking after finding the first occurrence of an id.  Google to find a GetElementByClassName function, it's on here.

Comment: Wait, never mind.  @AnthonyGrist, the JSFiddle that you gave me before was different, I figured it out.

Comment: @MattP Yes, `getElementById()` will only ever return one element. This is just to illustrate that it can be done. If you wanted to toggle more than one at a time, you'd need to use a class or - as Flambino suggested - select them based on the tag name.

Comment: @Flambino— **do not** use *inline* for BR elements. By default they don't have any [display property value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html). They should be toggled between 'none' and '' (empty string). That allows them to adopt whatever default or computed display property they might otherwise have.

Comment: @RobG I stand corrected. I admit I was partly guessing when I said `inline`, although I did wonder if a _linebreak_ could really be said to be _inline_. Did test it though, and it worked, so I figured I was on safe ground. Seems I wasn't :)